# Routing, Sub-domain Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

Our Client have a website like

```
www.example.com
```

Built on **codeigniter**. and there

```
www.example.com/some_user_name
```

goes to **routes.php** and redirect to

```
www.example.com/organisation/home/some_user_id
```

Now client wants

```
www.some_user_name.com
```

act as www.example.com/some_user_name

So we said no to him and suggested subdomain

```
some_user_name.example.com
```

but while integrating through godaddy server
it recommending Document Root which actually doesn't exist. 
So we are unable to provide https://some_user_name.com and https://some_user_name.example.com both. Please Help!

Comment: it is not possible to create the domain name same as the user name... If it is available the shift all content on that server which connect to www.some_user_name.com. for that you have to by the another domain(name : user_name.com if available) & hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution1:**

To get get the some_user_name.example.com you need to add the A entry from your panel. If you are using the CPANEL you can goto the dns zone editor and add the A record and in the path field you need to specify the folder name. I am not sure how to add entry to the Godaddy panel but below link will help you.
https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-20047

**Solution2:**

If you are using the CodeIgniter PHP framework go to the **application/config/routes.php**

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
    case 'some_username.example.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "some_username";
    break;
    case 'other_username.mysite.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "other_username";
    default:
        // The list of your $routes lines at is was...
    break;
}
```

Just specify the subdomain with specific controller name in the route file.

I think 2nd solution will help you more. Accept my answer if you got the solution.

Regards

Comment: Your solution is I think near to me, I have to do

case 'some.example.com'
and then
$x = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$route['default'] = 'org/home/'.$x[0]

????

Comment: Why do you want to use explode? If your url structure like the some_username.example.com than you need to try like above. **$route['default']** you need to specify the controller name.

Comment: but there is no such controller like some_username
i have to check on database and have to fetch corresponding id

Comment: You have to specify your own controller name there. Replace your own controller name with some_username